# Image not displayed in ie and chrome

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have an image tag in which i have given src attribute to http://mydomain/attachment.php?attachmentid=391&thumb=1.

```
<img width='100' height='75' border='0' src='../attachment.php?attachmentid=$picture[attachmentid]&amp;thumb=1'/>
```

It displays properly in firefox but when i check in ie & chrome the image is not displayed. I even tried to copy the url & then execute it directly in the browser same thing happened. This thing is happening in wordpress php exec widget.

I am unable to find out the cause for this.

Please help me on this.

Regards,

Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

Firefox is more tolerant when it comes to image headers then IE and Chrome.
What is propably the case, is that the images displayed by your script do not have the  expected headers to let IE/Chrome correctly identify them as real images.

You should toy around a little with headers like:

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
```

An interesting read perhaps: [here](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1269).

Comment: +1 Good guess, I've missed that it's image generated by php script.

Comment: Thanks Wesley for replying. I cannot add this code in widget as i am getting error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm not familiar with wordpress and it's widgets, but this means that output is sent to the buffer (f.e. echo / var_dump) before the header() function is called.